# Unable to run MongoDB on Android

Tags: java, android, mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB, I'm trying to make an Android App which is able to get Data from local MongoDB database.
I've correctly implemented Java Drivers in NetBeans, my java class works well, because I am able to get informations from my local DB, but when I try to implement the same class in Android, it doesn't work.
Here is the code

```
try{       
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );              
     // Now connect to your databases
     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "login" );
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");                
     DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("Utenti");
     while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
        System.out.println("Inserted Document: "+i); 
        DBObject oggettoAttuale = cursor.next();
     }
}catch(Exception e) {System.err.println("err");}
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Do you have error ? Please add the exception to the post.

Comment: From their download page, it doesn't look like MongoDB is supported on the Android platform => https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community

You need to get the correct hostname of the machine where the MongoDB server is running, and specify that in your code. Since there is no MongoDB instance running on your Android device("localhost"), your code will throw an error.

Comment: Yes, on my localhost MongoDb is running, infact when I run this program in NetBeans it works, but in Android nothing is working and it doesn't throw any exception ...